# What does "in abstraction from" mean?

Tags: meaning

What is required in philosophy is a certain capacity for thinking about everyday concepts **in abstraction from** their everyday context, an ability distinct from the mathematical skill essential for being a good physicist.

Comment: You may already have discovered that ***abstract*** derives from Latin ***abstractus*** =  "drawn away". Your cited context is erudite / formal / literary phrasing, where in a more normal conversational context the highlighted words would probably be replaced by ***outside of, apart from,*** or similar. The *meaning* is simply that those everyday concepts need to be thought about *in isolation, in the abstract* (metaphorically, "divorced" from their everyday contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Mathematician who occasionally strays into philosophy speaking. Be careful with this -- "In abstraction" is really not synonymous with "outside of" or "divorced from". What is closer might be: "distilling the core meaning of everyday concepts", might you agree?

Comment: @PrimeMover  Golf ball, football, baseball, croquet ball, bowling ball, cricket ball, tennis ball. If I say "inertial projectile used in recreational activities", I have distilled the core meaning of the foregoing list of terms. At the same time, my new description is divorced from the particularities of the sports in that list. It's the same thing, I think.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "Divorced from" adds the connotation that it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @PrimeMover To me, that means "separated from", more than "nothing to do with". In any case, it's "drawn away from those particularities"; "abstracted", _independent_ of golf courses, baseball diamonds, and the rest. The M-W definition of "abstract" says "disassociated from any particular instance."

Comment: @Prime Mover: If we're going to get "philosophical", we should interpret the noun ***abstraction*** here fin light of the specific sub-definition of the verb **abstract**: *(transitive) To formulate (an idea, concept, etc.) by isolating the intrinsic properties of something or common characteristics of a number of diverse things, without reference to the peculiar properties of any particular example or instance; to consider (something) in the abstract, independently of its associations or attributes, or separately from something from which it is not physically separable. Frequently with from.*

Comment: ...which I guess means I agree with you that *to the cognoscenti*, OP's highlighted usage isn't exactly "outside of". But it's close enough, for non-philosophers who just want to learn ordinary English.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica ...in which case OP is more than welcome to consult a conventional dictionary.

Comment: @Prime Mover: It's easy for the likes of us to select the relevant dictionary definition here, and interpret it according to context. But most people won't have access to the subscription-only full OED from which I copied the above definition. A fairly lengthy & dense definition at that, buried within a dozen others, so not necessarily trivial for a non-native speaker to find. If this had been *yet another* question about Arthur Conan Doyle's Spiritualist tracts I might have just closevoted. But it's not, and my etymology-based approach here may be a  potentially useful pointer for others.